# intrinsic lock via synchronized still allowing object's attributes to be modified.

Tags: java, multithreading

In below example, we have 3 threads. StartConsole thread runs first (since the other 2 threads are sleep for a bit). StartConsole takes control of the intrinsick lock of myObject. But it immediately relinquishes that intrinsic lock with the wait() invocation. That wait() invocation allows other threads to use that object. That means tcpResponder, which waited a second via Thread.sleep, can increment the values of myObject. What happens next is udpResponder begins execution after 2 seconds and it takes control of intrinsic lock via synchronized and until user types input, then it invokes notify() and hands over control back to startConsole where it then prints out “Received ack from unit”. Question: how come startService can continue to modify myObject when udpResponder took control of its intrinsic lock? I tested this example and the value of myObject's list attribute was being incremented the whole time.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WaitNotifyThreads {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    // notifier
    public void udpResponder() throws InterruptedException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        synchronized (myObject) {
            System.out.println("Send ACK to socket server");
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Return key pressed.");
            myObject.notify();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void startConsole() throws InterruptedException{

        synchronized (myObject) {
            myObject.wait();
        }       
        System.out.println("Received ack from unit.");
    }

    public void tcpResponder() throws InterruptedException{
        // Test if we can modify myObject
        // while startConsole has invoked wait() on it.
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Random random = new Random();

            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                myObject.add(random.nextInt(1000));
                System.out.println("object size: " + myObject.list().size());
            }       
    }

    public void startService() {
        Thread udpResponder = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    udpResponder();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
        });

        Thread consoleResponder = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startConsole();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
        });

        Thread tcpResponder = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tcpResponder();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
        });

        udpResponder.start();
        consoleResponder.start();
        tcpResponder.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitNotifyThreads program = new WaitNotifyThreads();
        program.startService();
    }

}
```

myObject class:

```
public class MyObject {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public MyObject(){

    }

    public void add(int val){
        list.add(val);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> list(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
object size: 1
Send ACK to socket server
object size: 2
object size: 3
object size: 4
object size: 5
object size: 6
object size: 7
object size: 8

object size: 9
Return key pressed.
Received ack from unit.
object size: 10
object size: 11
object size: 12
```

After printing Send ACK to socket server, it should have not allowed it to modify myObject anymore until enter key pressed since udpResponder took control of myObject intrinsic lock.

Comment: If you want to prevent threads from invoking the `add` method you have to do it. I don’t see any attempt in your code. Your method `tcpResponder()` does not contain anything that would ever interact with other threads. Putting a comment like `// Test if we can modify myObject` in the code is **not** a test…

Answer (score 1):

Some Comments:

(1)  `synchronized(foo) {...}` does *not* prevent other threads from modifying `foo`.  It only prevents other threads from *synchronizing* on foo.  If you want to make sure that threads B, C, and D can not access some (collection of) state variable(s) while thread A is making changes, then every place where you code updates or uses the variable(s) must be synchronized on the same object.  It doesn't matter what object they all synchronize on.  It may even be an object that is not part of the shared state, but it must be the *same* object in each place.

That almost always means that the lock object will have the same scope as the data that it protects (e.g., if the data are static, then the lock will be static.  If the data are instance variables of some class, then the lock will be an instance variable of the same class,...)

(2) `foo.wait()` is allowed to return even if `foo.notify()` has not been called.  Always call wait() from within a loop:

```
// Thread A
synchronized (foo) {
    while (! conditionImWaitingFor()) {
        foo.wait();
    }
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

(3) `foo.notify()` does *nothing* if some other thread is not already waiting in `foo.wait()`.  So, if thread A calls foo.notify() just one time, and *then* thread B calls foo.wait(), thread B is going to wait forever.  Always call notify() like this:

```
// Thread B
synchronized (foo) {
    createTheConditionHesWaitingFor();
    foo.notify();
}
```

Notice how (2) and (3) work together.  If thread B runs first, then it will create the condition that thread A waits for.  It will call foo.notify() which will have no effect, but then when thread A gets to run, it will find that the condition is true, and it will not wait().  If thread A runs first, it will wait, but thread B is guaranteed to notify it and wake it up.